# Appropriate use of mediator pattern

Tags: design-patterns, c++11

I'm writing a program that has one class called `Driver`, which reads audio, sends it through an effects chain and then sends it to an audio output. The effects are created from dynamic libraries (using either LADSPA or LV2 interfaces). So I wrote a class called `DriverMediator` that manages the shared libraries that contain the effects, and the `Driver` class that uses the effects.

So is this a correct use case of the [Mediator Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [mediator](http://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html) shall encapsulate the interactions between colleagues.  The intent is to have a loose coupling between the colleagues.

It is not fully clear from your description if you use it rightly.  May be you do, but your description gives the impression that your `DriverMediator` just encapsulates all these objects and act as a kind of facade:

- do the `Driver` and your LADSPA/LV2 plugins all know the mediator and are capable to interact with it ?
- is the `Driver` independent of the libraries ?  Fo example, could you replace the libraries with completely different audio systems and still do not change the Driver ? Or does the `DriverMediator`  just forwards the calls, leaving the `Driver` indirectly dependent of the library ?

If it's still unclear, you could edit your question to give additional details about the interactions between all these objects.

Comment: it sounds like I was using more of the facade pattern, after reading about it and reading your answer. I'm just going to rename `DriverMediator` to `DriverFacade`